# mvc code first modelling multiple relationships - simple example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity

I have two Entities in an MVC app:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Forename {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}

public class SubGroup
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to use Code First to create a relationship between them. The relationship is that each user can be a member of 0 or more subgroups.

Please can someone suggest the best way to do this because I have seen a few examples on SO and I'm confused. I've seen stuff about implementing ICollections in a class, other stuff about using the fluent API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICollections approach:
UPDATE:

If I understand correctly you have many-to-many relationship (group have many users, user have can be in many groups), in that case code should be like this:

```
        public class RelationExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubGroup> SubGroups { get; set; }

}


public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubGroup> SubGroups { get; set; } 
}

public class SubGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Adding Users to groups example:

```
 var db = new RelationExampleContext();

var subGroups = new List<SubGroup>
                                {
                                    new SubGroup() {Name = "Subgroup1"},
                                    new SubGroup() {Name = "Subgroup2"}
                                };

            var users = new List<User>
                            {
                                new User()
                                    {
                                        Forename = "Forename1",
                                        Surname = "Surname1",
                                        SubGroups = new List<SubGroup>
                                                        {
                                                            subGroups.First(),
                                                            subGroups.Last()
                                                        }
                                    },
                                new User()
                                    {
                                        Forename = "Forename2",
                                        Surname = "Surname2",
                                        SubGroups = new List<SubGroup>
                                                        {
                                                            subGroups.First()
                                                        }
                                    }
                            };

            foreach (var subGroup in subGroups)
            {
                db.SubGroups.Add(subGroup);
            }

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is a great reply and just what I was looking for - thanks! What do I need to do in Visual Studio 2010 to see the relationship diagram like the one you have posted above?

Comment: To display diagram you should generate edmx model. But edmx model not require if you choose CodeFirst approach. edmx model used often with DataBase first approach or Model first. But if you still want to add edmx model you may creeate it in menu: Add > New Item > ADO.NET Entity Data Model > Generate From Database.

Comment: I've seeded some data in the ContextInitializer. I've created two new Users and added them to the context. Then I've created two new SubGroups and added a new List<User>() to each. The first user is a member of groups 1 and 2, the second a member of group just group 1. But when I do a query it's showing the SubGroupID for group 1 only. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess User and SubGroup has the same Tables in database 
you need create relation table between this tables (fields User_id, Group_id) 
model for new entity like UserGroups

and then you can create composition  in User class

Comment: OK, so create another table. What do you mean by "create composition in User class"?

Comment: i thought you asked about pattern Composite http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

i mean something like this 
`code`
public class UserGrops
{

    public __construct( UserId ) {}
    public function getGrops () { ....  ...  }
}

public class User {
// new property userGrops

// add method 
   public function grops ()
{
   this.userGroups = new UserGrops(this.ID)
}
}

and you can use construction 
user.grops.getGrops()
`code`

I hope you understand idea i'm using another programming language